# trigger focus event will fires blur event(without use alert and browser console)

Tags: javascript, onfocus

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/newhuan/wees38js/7/)

`<input id = "focus-ipt"  type = "text" value = "nothing" />`

```
var $focusIpt = document.querySelector( "#focus-ipt" );
$focusIpt.addEventListener( "blur", function ( e ) {
   $focusIpt.value = "blured!";
} );
setTimeout( function () {
    $focusIpt.focus();
    }, 1000 );
```

I just trigger focus event,but blur event fired after focus;
I searched for a long time, close the console, use setTimeout,however, can't solve it;I really don't konw how this happened,can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure there is no focus event listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually **not** the case; **[`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)** does not automatically trigger **[`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)**.

The `blur()` is getting triggered because you are interacting with the DOM. By clicking on one of the buttons in your fiddle (such as `Run` or `Tidy`), the `#focus-ipt` element is no longer active -- the button you're clicking on is.

If you simply wait the time out, without doing anything, the `blur()` event won't occur. As soon as you click off of the input, the `blur()` **will** occur.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
var $focusIpt = document.querySelector("#focus-ipt");
$focusIpt.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  $focusIpt.value = "Blurred!";
});
setTimeout(function() {
  $focusIpt.focus();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input id="focus-ipt" type="text" id="myText" value="Sample Text">
<button type="button">Click me to lose focus</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I open the link,without doing anyting, and blur fired; And I write the code in a html file , run it by chrome,without any click,but blur event is still fired;would you please copy the code and run ? Sorry,but this really confuse me for many days.

Comment: I run your code,just click the "Run code snippet" button,when the color of the button change from deep to shallow,the value changes to "Blurred!"

Comment: `blur()` does not automatically fire when you open your JSFiddle link. You are indeed doing something to make the `blur()` occur. My example does not automatically blur for me, neither does your JSFiddle.

Comment: What browser are you using? And what version of that browser do you have? It may be behaviour unique to a particular browser.

Comment: I get it! I close all the expanded program of chrome,and ..... it works....,Sorry, really sorry for wasting your time..... and thank you very much!

Comment: the expanded program “Surfingkeys” cause this problem